# is there a OpenSocial plugin for .NET

Tags: asp.net, webforms, opensocial

Is there a good NET framework opensocial nuget package or addin available. searching on stackoverflow it appears this question was asked 3 years ago and a mature active library wasn't available.

Tim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the one that used to be used by MySpace http://code.google.com/p/negroni/